# Is there a way to drag and drop in Trello on Android browsers?

Tags: trello, android

Is it possible to drag and drop cards between boards at the board level using a mobile browser? Or is that just rephrasing the question "when will there be a native android app"?

I can log into Trello using Opera browser on Android, and the format of boards and cards is displayed ok. But the easiest way to move cards is to open the card and use its move dropdown. So it's possible, just less intuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently. Trello doesn't use the touch events used in iOS and Android browsers, so things like drag and drop will not work.

You can tap the card menu (the button in the top right corner of the card) and select 'Move'. It will let you move between boards, lists, and within a list.

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case, but wanted to be sure there wasn't something I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: It is almost 2024, 12 years later! And the Trello web app still does not support drag and drop with touch events? Incredible!

Answer (score 2):

An Android Trello app is now available and it allows you to drag and drop a card by long pressing on it. Just use the app. The Trello web application in Android browsers still doesn't have drag and drop support.